# Why my program to change webhook avatar from url doesnt work in discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

my program in discord.py dont work. I want to make `!rules` command that will create webhook and send message with rules. I have a problem while trying set up a avatar.

````py
async def rules(self,ctx,*args):
        respone=f"This is rules of **{ctx.guild.name}** server."
        numba=1
        for o in args:
            respone=respone+f"```{numba}. {o}```"
            numba=numba+1
        web=await ctx.channel.create_webhook(name='Rules')
        await web.edit(avatar_url="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2021/01/19/03/56/girl-5929995_960_720.jpg")
        await web.send(respone)
        await ctx.author.send(f"Because command will be deleted, here's backup of it: \n`{ctx.message.content}`")
        await ctx.message.delete()
````

Can someone help? I tried using these images:

```
https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2021/02/08/16/03/dinosaur-5995333_960_720.png (png)
https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/731900211428851744/03adc5705993b66267666ff67be84d34.webp (my discord avatar, webp)
https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2021/01/19/03/56/girl-5929995_960_720.jpg (jpg)
```

Thank you.

Comment: Any error something?

Comment: I invited you on Discord.

Answer (score 0):

Try await web.edit(avatar=ctx.author.avatar_url)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i don't wanna use author avatar but my link for image.

Comment: So web.avatar_url